# rawQuery() in Android SQLite not compiling parameters

Tags: android, sqlite, parameters

While trying to implement SQLite storage ran into strange behavior.
The "?"-symbols are not substituted.

My code:

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public void writeTask(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      String id = object.get(OBJECT_ID).toString();
      String content = object.toString();
      String md5 = "md5"; //testing

      Cursor c = db.rawQuery("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ? ( ? , ? , ? ) VALUES ( ? , ? , ?);", new String[] {TABLE_OBJECTS, OBJECT_ID, OBJECT_CONTENT, OBJECT_MD5, id, content, md5 });
  }
}
```

Then it throws a strange error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ? ( ? , ? , ? ) VALUES ( ? , ? , ?);
```

First mistake corrected, but still not working:

```
 String selectQuery = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO " + TABLE_OBJECTS + " ("
            + OBJECT_ID + "," + OBJECT_CONTENT + "," + OBJECT_MD5 + ") "
            + "VALUES ( ? , ? , ?);";
 String[] args = { id, content, md5 };
            Log.d("FP", selectQuery);

 Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,args);
```

Now database is untouched after this query. Logs show my query:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO objects (id,content,md5) VALUES (?,?,?);
```

Any suggestions?

so, **rawQuery()** is just for **SELECT**.

But i still need to do escaping special characters, because **content**-variable is a stringified JSON and execSQL does not allow this.

Comment: hmmm rawQuery for inserts .. interesing choice ... obviously there is a similar api with `db.insert` with `ContentValues` ....

Comment: tried to use something like **UPSERT** and found example with **INSERT OR REPLACE**

Comment: there is a shorcut for `INSERT OR REPLACE` in `SQliteDatabase` class ... just take a look at the docs .... the name of the method should be obvious ... maybe, well, hmmm, `replace` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `?` only for binding literals such as those in your `VALUES()`, not for identifiers such as table or column names earlier in your SQL.

If you need to use variables for identifiers, use regular string concatenation in Java.

Also note that `rawQuery()` alone won't execute your SQL. Consider using `execSQL()` instead.

Comment: ah, rawQuery is just for **SELECT**

Comment: You can use it for any SQL but you'll need to move the cursor the execute it. Therefore you shouldn't use it for other than selects and the like.